# Triangulate given convex polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons, computational-geometry

Suppose given a convex polygon  $P$ with $n$ vertices in the plane. It's possible to triangulate $P$ such that for each given line $\ell$, $\ell$ cross at most $O(\log n)$ triangles?

My attempt:

I think [Delaney Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) can help us but I have no idea that how we must change the algorithm to handle this case.

Comment: @PrudiiArca I edit the post.

Comment: I think you can just divide the n-gon in half (or as close as possible) using a diagonal, and then recursively subdivide those two halves in the same way.

Comment: Thank you. How this idea can guarantee that for each given line $\ell$ cross at most $O(\log n)$ triangles?

Comment: You basically have to show that O(log(n/2))+O(log(n/2)) is still O(log n).

Comment: $\log(\frac{n}{2})+\log(\frac{n}{2})=O(\log n)$. But my problem is how you achieve $\log(\frac{n}{2})$?

Comment: If it is possible please post your answer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Are there any reference for this problem?